# Transfer content from EditText to another activity on buttonclick

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-edittext

I need to transfer the contents of an EditText to another activity on Button click.

This is my current code for start of new activity:

```
Button proceed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);

    proceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bProceed);
    proceed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Introscreen.this, BillardScoreboardActivity.class);
            Introscreen.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            myIntent.putExtra ??????
        }
    }); 
}
```

The contents are supposed to be integers in the next activity.

Hope someone can help me.

**Final problem:**

```
Intent i = getIntent()  //Error message if ";" isn't put after getintent()
String var = i.getStringExtra("lol");
int convert = Integer.parseInt(var); //Error message if ";" is put after getIntent()
```

Comment: EditView? Do you mean EditText?

Comment: see it is random varaiable name and if You Passing directly any variable i.e 'String s = 10 ' then write  myIntent.putExtra("you_custom_variable_name",s); if you passing any random name write like  myIntent.putExtra("you_custom_variable_name","name");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EdiText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
String s = ed.getText.toString();
public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Introscreen.this, BillardScoreboardActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("you_custom_variable_name",s);
    startActivity(myIntent);
   }
```

Reveiver Side Write

```
  Intent i = getIntent();
  String var = i.getStringExtra("you_custom_variable_name");
  int convert = Integer.parseInt(var);
```

THis is Simple Method

Comment: "you_custom_variable_name" - I guess i can just write whatever i want (some random shit)? Or is it a variable i've already specified somewhere?

Comment: I prefer tick marking when i've confirmed that it works for me :)

Comment: I've updated the question with a final tiny problem, if you don't mind helping :)