# Moving text from one activity to another

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I have one question on activity. I have two activities, in first activity I have one edit text box and one submit button. when I enter some text in edit text and press submit button it should go to 2nd activity and should display the text entered in the 1st activity

Comment: see my this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414477/transfer-content-from-editview-to-another-activity-on-buttonclick/9414536#9414536 example where i am passing EditText data from one Activity to Aonther Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Do that on yor first Activity:

```
private void goToSecondActivity() {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    String myText = editText.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("text", myText);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And on the second activity, on your onCreate method:

```
String myText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("text");
```